# Get String value between two strings through javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, taxonomy

I want to get the string value between **";L0|"** and **";GTSet"** from the following type of strings.

```
var test = "GP0|#9d72d96c-407f-4e45-b2e6-9361faf5808a;L0|#09d72d96c-407f-4e45-b2e6-9361faf5808a|Travel;GTSet|#ac96f075-b7d2-4e90-8dc2-da8875f395fc";
var test2 = "GP0|#15a06b93-f7aa-4dda-b0d6-7bf2d2905f27;L0|#015a06b93-f7aa-4dda-b0d6-7bf2d2905f27|Special Event;GTSet|#ac96f075-b7d2-4e90-8dc2-da8875f395fc";
```

Here is what i have done already.

```
var str = test2.match(";L0|" + "(.*?)" + ";GTSet");
 alert(str[1]);
```

and this returns a string from the very beginning till the ";GTSet"

[Jsfiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/tkP74/3325/)

Comment: `match(/;L0\|(.*?);GTSet/)`

Comment: `|` has a special meaning in an regex. Right now you're looking for `";L0"` **or** `"(.*?);GTSet"`

Comment: or `match(new RegExp(";L0\\|" + "(.*?)" + ";GTSet"))` (double escapes in a string)

Comment: a fast non-regexp way: `str.split(";GTSet")[0].split(";L0|")[1]`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I managed to get the required string using your comments like below.

var test3 = "GP0|#0433927f-0f80-4e5b-a19c-e97c7ebb2398;L0|#00433927f-0f80-4e5b-a19c-e97c7ebb2398|Dealer Visit;GTSet|#ac96f075-b7d2-4e90-8dc2-da8875f395fc"

var str = test3.match(new RegExp(";L0\\|" + "(.*?)" + ";GTSet"));
alert(str[1].split('|')[1]);

Comment: @ChathuraSam Why are you writing the pattern as three seperate strings anyway?

Comment: thank you @dandavis. it is much faster

Comment: @m69 because i might be passing the two string parameters later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are getting this value from SharePoint Search results, right? If so, according to [Automatically created managed properties in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136(v=office.15).aspx):

> **Data format for Managed Metadata.**
>
> To query for items tagged with a Managed Metadata field, you have to
>   use the Unique Identifier for each label. You can find the Unique
>   Identifier for each term in a term set in the Term Store Management
>   Tool, on the GENERAL tab. In addition, the data format that is used in
>   the query has to specify from which level in the term set the query
>   should apply. This specification is set by adding one of the following
>   prefixes to the Unique Identifier:
>
> - To query for all items that are tagged with a term: `GP0|#`
> - To query for all items that are tagged with a child of term: `GPP|#`
> - To query for all items that are tagged with a term from a term set: `GTSet|#`

Based on this information the following example demonstrates *how to parse search result value for managed metadata*:

```js
function parseTaxonomySearchResultValue(val){
    var taxValue = {TermSetGuids: [], TermValues: []};
    var parts = val.split(';');
    parts.forEach(function(part){
       if (part.startsWith("GP0|#")) //term?
       {
           var termGuid = part.replace("GP0|#", "");
           taxValue.TermValues.push({ TermGuid: termGuid});
       }
       else if (part.startsWith("GTSet|#")) //term set?
       {
            taxValue.TermSetGuids.push(part.replace("GTSet|#", ""));
       }
       else if (part.startsWith("L0|#")) //Term with label?
       {
            var termParts = part.replace("L0|#0", "").split('|');
            var termGuid = termParts[0];
            var termLabel = termParts[1];
            var result = taxValue.TermValues.filter(function(tv){  
                return tv.TermGuid == termGuid;
            });
            if (result.length == 0)
                taxValue.TermValues.push({TermGuid : termGuid, Label : termLabel});
            else
                result[0].Label = termLabel;
        }
    });
    return taxValue;
}


//Usage
var taxValue = 'GP0|#9d72d96c-407f-4e45-b2e6-9361faf5808a;L0|#09d72d96c-407f-4e45-b2e6-9361faf5808a|Travel;GTSet|#ac96f075-b7d2-4e90-8dc2-da8875f395fc';
var taxValue = parseTaxonomySearchResultValue(taxValue);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Term info:<br/>" + "Guid= " + taxValue.TermValues[0].TermGuid + "<br/> Label= " + taxValue.TermValues[0].Label;
```

```html
<div id='output'/>
```